# Date Comparison NSPredicate

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Case 1:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" end_time < '2015-07-27 06:22:43 +0000'"]
```

crashed

```
reason: '-[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector
```

Case 2:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" end_time < 2015-07-27 06:22:43 +0000"]
```

crashed

```
 reason: 'Unable to parse the format string " end_time < 2015-07-27 06:22:43 +0000"'
```

Case 3:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" end_time < %@",[NSDate date]
```

works!

Can someone explain me the difference between the three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First case:**

`endTime < '2015-07-27 06:22:43 +0000'`. I'm sure that the data type of `endTime` is `NSDate`. The runtime tried to treat the rhs as a date object as well and tried to compare. But it is a string. Crash.

**Second case:**

This is simply the wrong syntax. There is a whitespace after `2015-07-27`. Runtime doesn't know how to parse this. Crash.

(Even if your predicate was, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"end_time < 2015-07-27"]`, it would be a valid predicate format. But would crash because of `unrecognized selector` on `NSNumber`? I am not sure.)

**Third case:**

rhs is a date object. lhs is a date object. `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` is called on an `NSDate` instance. Works.

Comment: as you mentioned @"end_time < 2015-07-27" , this statement would lead to crash but i tried it and it didn't lead to crash .But now I am unable to get how this is working and it not tries to call 'timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate'  on '2015-07-27' ?

Comment: I am not sure. I know it is a valid parse format. My thoughts were that 2015-07-27 will be treated as an arithmetic operation on numbers and translated to endTime <  (2015-7)-27. I am not sure why this isn't crashing. Hmm...

Comment: for @" end_time > %d",2015-07-27 , this is also getting crash , how come this possible?

Comment: This crashes because now, you are explicitly setting the type. The runtime will try to treat it as a `NSNumber` and crashes. In the former example maybe -- only maybe -- it took the "convenient" type. Again, I am not sure.